# Angular 2 routing with ASP .Net Core (non-mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up routing with .net core and Angular 2 but the routes do not resolve because they are resolved by the server.

One solution I have seen is to register a default route to your home controller or something... but I don't have any MVC controllers.

I've added this to my main component (and done all the other router prerequisites)

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Table', component: TableComp, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComp }
])
```

And I do have these in startup.cs:

within ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddMvc();
```

within Configure()

```
app.UseMvc();
```

But since I'm not actually using any MVC Controllers or registering any MVC routes, I'm at a loss as to how to get my angular routes to resolve in the browser rather than the server, and why they aren't just doing the thing...

Comment: I suggest using a single MVC controller to serve a single Index.cshtml view. This allows you to take advantage of asp.net built in routing and tag helpers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following configuration should fit most projects using client side routing in .NET Core:

```
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
})
.UseCors("AllowAll")
.UseMvc()
.UseDefaultFiles(options)
.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: Would this be added to the RouteConfig or something? Or what file would I add this to?

Comment: Tested and works. This also works without UseCors and UseMvc.

Comment: @Brett this should be added in de Startup.Configure method variable app is the IApplicationBuilder

Comment: Just a note, if anyone is confused: `Path` comes from `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#microsoftaspnetcorespaservices) found in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) github repo. Look for this [example](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#microsoftaspnetcorespaservices).

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

There is an [older post](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/) here with some previous versions, but the setup should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [example](https://github.com/deeptowncitizen/aspcore-docker) Asp Core + Angular2 + Swashbuckle + Docker.

It uses `UseMvc()` for C# API controllers. And `UseStaticFiles()` to serve AngularJs (and other static) files.

So you're running Asp Core backend as service. Using Webpack you can build AngularJs application from Typescript source code. It will be published to `public` folder Backend looks to serve statics from.

Answer (score 0):

I put index.html in wwwroot and use DefaultFiles() in start up page.  The webserver knows and finds the default file - index.html automatically.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```